# Setting priority of a process without using nice and/or renice command

Tags: c, linux, unix

Is there a way to set the priority of a process without using nice and renice command in linux.

Everywhere I search I find the solutions for setting priority only using nice and renice command. I need to set the priority of a process without using these two commands.

I there a way to achieve this?

My applications are C applications running on linux platform. If there is a way to do it by doing it within the application is also ok.

Comment: What is the issue you have with `nice` or `renice`?

Comment: See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpriority.2.html and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html

Comment: @hek2mgl it is is just that the flavor of linux devices which I use doesnt support the nice and renice commands. not that there is something wrong with them. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A C program can use `setpriority()` to cause itself (or some other process, or process group, or all processes for a given user), to have less (or, with sufficient privileges, i.e. if running as root, more) favourable scheduling priority.  See its manual page for further information.